# Map of priority queues

Tags: c++, priority-queue, unordered-map

I am trying to write a map of pairs of priority queues to be exact.
I am really unsure on how to initialize and element before I add it to the map.
Especially when the pair doesn´t exist and I have to create it and then fill one element queue up one element into the right queue and then insert the whole pair into the map.

```
typedef pair<priority_queue<myType>, priority_queue<myType>> Queue_Pair;
typedef unordered_map<string, Queue_Pair>  Map_of_Queues;
Map_of_Queues myMap;
```

So how do I insert a myType into a priority queue into a pair into the map?
I will have to do multiple checks before I insert the element into the right queue so this would be really helpful to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get a reference to the Queue_Pair associated with "key"
// If it doesn't yet exist, create it.
Queue_Pair& qp = myMap["key"];

// add an element to the first priority queue
qp.first.push(myType_object);

// add an element to the second priority queue
qp.second.push(another_myType_object);
```

Note that you could just do this:

```
myMap["key"].first.push(myType_object);
```

But if you're going to reuse the associated `Queue_Pair` multiple times in sequence, this will incur the lookup cost each time, so it is better to store it in a reference first, then use that reference.